# How can I change only one value in a React useState that contains an object and assign a different one to the rest?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, state, use-state

I have the following State:

```
const [clickColumn, setClickColumn] = useState({
    name: 0,
    tasks: 0,
    partner: 0,
    riskFactor: 0,
    legalForm: 0,
    foundationYear: 0
  })
```

And now, for example, I only want to set name to 2 and the rest to 1. But I do not want to write it this way: `setClickColumn({ name: 2, tasks: 1, riskFactor: 1, partner: 1, legalForm: 1, foundationYear: 1 });`

How can I make it shorter?

Comment: Are you using it for forms?

Answer (score 12):

You can use spread operator to make it simple:

```
setClickColumn({ ...clickColumn, name: 2 });
```

it spreads the existing object clickColumn and adds the name: 2 to it, overriding the default value.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Comment: I wish I could upvote this more than once...

Answer (score 2):

Making it shorter wouldn't necessarily make it more simple, but you can do something like this:

```js
const obj = {
  name: 0,
  tasks: 0,
  partner: 0,
  riskFactor: 0,
  legalForm: 0,
  foundationYear: 0
};

const entries = Object.entries(obj).map(([key, value]) => key === 'name' ? [key, 2] : [key, 1]);
const result = Object.fromEntries(entries);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: setClickColumn(Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(clickColumn).map(([key, value]) => [key, key === 'name' ? 2 : 1])))

Comment: @Eran yes, but I thought it's pretty straight forward from here :)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily create a function that will reset the state for you by parsing the object and give the right value:

```js
const getResetClickColumn = (clickColumn) => {
  Object.keys(clickColumn).forEach(key => {
    const value = (key === 'name' ? 2 : 1);
    clickColumn[key] = value;
  })

  return clickColumn;
}

const reset = getResetClickColumn({
  name: 0,
  tasks: 0,
  partner: 0,
  riskFactor: 0,
  legalForm: 0,
  foundationYear: 0
})

console.log(reset)
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @MorKadosh 's answer:

```
setClickColumn(Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(clickColumn)
   .map(([key, value]) => [key, key === 'name' ? 2 : 1])))
```

Answer (score -2):

You can simply make a temp variable

```
let tmpColumn = clickColumn;
tmpColumn.name = 2;
// other changes
setClickColumn(tmpColumn);
```

Comment: this is not a proper way to make an object copy

Comment: @KrzysztofKrzeszewski Why ? Can you explain ?

Comment: @BloodyMonkey it is alright as long as you don't care about immutability. In the snippet you provided you mutate the object directly, and since it is important to keep objects immutable when dealing with react components state, it is a no-no.  I didn't downvote btw, even though it's a pretty bad answer

Comment: when you use this syntax, you are not actually creating the copy of the object, you are only copying the reference, in your example modifying the property name of the newly created variable will also modify the property name of the clickColumn

Comment: Ok thanks, i was aware of imutability of states, but not of the reference copy instead of value